# ODE homogeneous kernal collides with non-homogeneous kernel then times t, why.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

This post is a call back to one of my old questions that got no response. That is, why multiply an extra t (but not anything else) when we get repeated roots from either the characteristic polynomial of the linear ODE or from getting repeated roots from the homogeneous kernel and the non-homogeneous kernel? The reasoning goes like,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with expressing the linear ODE system with linear algebra.

> Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. $x_o\in\mathbb{C}$ are the initial condition. The IVP $\dot{x} = \mathbf{A}x,\ x(0) = x_0$ has a unique solution given by $x(t)=e^{\mathbf{A}t}x_0$.

Let $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{J}\mathbf{P}$ where $\mathbf{J}$ is in Jordan normal form. We also denote the Jordan block w.r.t the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue by $J_i$.

> $\mathbf{J}=(J_i)=\bigg(\begin{bmatrix}
>     \lambda_i & 1 & \cdots & & 0\\
>     \vdots & \lambda_i & 1 & & \\
>       & & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
>       & & & \lambda_i & 1\\
>     0 & & & \cdots & \lambda_i\\
> \end{bmatrix}\bigg)$

Now we have,

> $x(t) = e^{\mathbf{A}t}x_0=\mathbf{P}^{-1}e^{\mathbf{J}t}\mathbf{P}x_0\implies y(t)=e^{\mathbf{J}t}y_0$

We further decompose $\mathbf{J} = \lambda_i\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{\Lambda}$. Notice $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is nilpotent. The upper off-diagonal shifts up k times in $\mathbf{\Lambda}^k.$ Suppose $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is a nilpotent operator of order $k+1$.

> \begin{align*} e^{\mathbf{J}t}=e^{\lambda_i\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{\Lambda}t}&=e^{\lambda_i\mathbf{I}t}e^{\mathbf{\Lambda}t}\\ &=e^{\lambda_i\mathbf{I}t}\cdot(\Sigma\frac{\mathbf{\Lambda}^n}{n!}t^n)\\ &=e^{\lambda_i\mathbf{I}t} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & t & \frac{t^2}{2} & \cdots &  & \frac{t^k}{k!}\\
>     & 1 & t & \frac{t^2}{2} &\cdots & \frac{t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\\
>     & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\
>     & & & 1 & t & \frac{t^2}{2} \\
>     & & & & 1 & t \\
>      & & & & & 1 \\
> \end{bmatrix}\end{align*}

When $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is nilpotent of order 1, we simply get the diagonal part. If the  $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ corresponding to $\lambda_i$ (the roots of the characteristic polynomial) has multiplicity of 2 (repeated roots), we get the extra $t$ multiplied with that root. Moreover, $\mathbf{P}$ consists of things called generalized eigenvectors.

e.g.

> $\ddot{x}=0 \implies \dot{\textbf{x}}=\mathbf{A}\textbf{x}$ where $\textbf{x}=(x, \dot{x})^{T}$ and $\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. The solution $e^{\mathbf{A}t}$ is then $\begin{bmatrix}1 & t \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\cdot \textbf{x}_0=(c_1+c_2t, c_2)^{T}$